# How to loop through a nested JSON object and save the multiple key-value pairs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, stack, iteration

I have an interesting issue, and I have the logic of the problem down but I am not having luck coming up with a solution.

Basically, I have JSON objects (which could be of any shape or size) similar to the one listed below:

```
    {
  "keyHigh": {
    "title": "Sign In Page",
    "key2": {
      "keyA": "Hey!",
      "keyB": "This!",
      "keyC": "Is!",
      "keyD": "All!",
      "keyE": "Example!",
      "keyF": "Content!",
      "keyG": "Hopefully!"
    },
    "key3": {
      "keyH": "This!",
      "keyI": "Illustrates!",
      "keyJ": "My Point!",
      "keyK": "Please!",
      "keyL": "Help!"
    },
    "key4": "/test.html#/"
  }
}
```

Now, what I am trying to accomplish, is that I want to loop through JSON objects (similar to the one above) and produce a "keys" value pair of sorts. I am hoping to be able to produce a table like the one below, using $ to separate keys:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Tag</th>
    <th>Content</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$keyHigh$title</td>
    <td>Sign In Page<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$keyHigh$key2$keyA</td>
    <td>Hey!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$keyHigh$key2$keyB</td>
    <td>This!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$keyHigh$key2$keyC</td>
    <td>Is!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$keyHigh$key3$keyJ</td>
    <td>My Point!<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$keyHigh$key4</td>
    <td>/test.html#/</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

NOTE**** I want all of the "tags", not just specific "tags"

How should I go about getting these multiple-key value pairs in a dynamic way?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery for `$.each` loop and `append` function, but this can also be achieved with pure JS.

```
function layOut(keyString, obj) {
  if (typeof obj == "object") {
    $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
      layOut(keyString + "$" + key, val);
    });
  } else {
    $("table.layout").append("<tr><td>" + keyString + "</td><td>" + obj +"</td></tr>");
  }
}
```

The idea is to check if the deepest level is achieved. This can be done using `typeof`. For the start call you need to pass empty string as a `keyString`. So it will be `layOut("", obj);`